# Get RPC URL / IP of Metamask's current provider

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, metamask, web3-providers

Suppose I have multiple copies of the same dapp running on different servers which do not directly communicate with each other, for testing purposes, and can manually interact with different dapp instances by changing which network I point Metamask to.

I would like to be able to show, on-screen, which network I am currently connected to (including the host address of my current provider), via client code.  Then, when I generate screenshots or printouts, it is clear exactly which server I was connected to when that content was generated, without having to open MetaMask and show its network selector for every screenshot (not available for printouts).  This can help eliminate speculation that an issue was caused by having an incorrect network selection in MetaMask.

More detail (skip for tl;dr): The client connects through MetaMask to a blockchain node hosted *somewhere,* which might be 127.0.0.1 or on a server that is part of the Infura service, or on some other machine which happens to be hosting a node for the blockchain I'm interested in reading from. It may be that there are multiple different IP addresses hosting the same blockchain (as part of a dapp) but the client will only connect to one at a time. Being able to show which one I'm reading from would also be helpful in checking for any differences between the nodes when, for example, they wind up on different sides of a virtual network partition and have no peer-to-peer communication path.

I can do `web3.currentProvider` and get a Proxy object revealing the selected address and network identifier code (which is 1 for mainnnet and small integers for big public testnets and settable for private networks; Ganache's default is 5777).  This network identifier is useful but not sufficient by itself.  I have not yet found a property or method I can call to get the IP address (or name set in MetaMask, which would seem less likely to be there).

Documentation on Provider objects is limited, but source code is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/1.0/packages/web3-providers/src/providers) and the base class AbstractSocketProvider is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/packages/web3-providers/lib/providers/AbstractSocketProvider.js).

What am I  missing?  How would I programmatically find out the current network address of the blockchain node the client is interacting with?

---

Here is a more concrete example of what I'm trying to do, following a comment by @RobHitchens:

MetaMask has a network selector at the top of the interface, which looks like this at "Timepoint A:"
[image: Screenshot]

If you click the arrow in the right side of the bubble, there's a drop-down which shows other options, including Custom RPC.  Clicking that takes you to a settings menu and scrolling down allows the input of a "New RPC URL" like this:

[image: Screenshot]

In that box, you can enter another IP address like "http://192.168.1.24:1234" (for another machine on a local network, for example).  Clicking Save, that string becomes a new and currently-selected option in the network selector dropdown:
[image: Screenshot]
I'll call this timepoint B.  For purposes of this question, assume MetaMask successfully connects (no loading symbol next to that URL).

I would like a function I can programmatically call that will at timepoint A return "http://127.0.0.1:7545" and at timepoint B return "http://192.168.1.24:1234" with no change to the dapp/client source code between those timepoints.  It's OK if there are multiple functions which each return part of the information needed to construct that return value.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: blockchains don't have an IP - they're a decentralized network. Only nodes which connect to the blockchain have IPs but finding a node's IP doesn't tell you anything about where it's connected to.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen That is correct.  I am referring to the IP of the node which the client is connected to.

Comment: Laurie has tried to explain. Your question doesn't make sense even rereading several times. There is just no correspondance to the topology of a distributed blockchain network or metamask/infura method of connecting to them.

Comment: @RobHitchens Do the new edits make the question more concrete and clear?

Comment: @WBT It seems like the end of your question is malformed; if you're trying to determine which of the Eth-based networks you're connecting to, then you need to check Metamask's `chainId` and map that over to the network names.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-chainid

Edit: Just saw you said chainId wouldn't do.  Why?  The specific node you're connected to is irrelevant here, the IP of the node you're speaking to doesn't actually identify the network in a meaningful way.

What do you need that checking chainId & genesis blocks wouldn't provide?

Comment: @ohsully That link is broken (HTTP 404), but assuming its contents match the description, it doesn't work for private chains.  Private chains in different environments with firewall rules allowing a client to talk to both but not allowing those nodes to talk to each other can have the same chainId but be different blockchain networks.  The IP address/hostname and port information can help distinguish between these.

Comment: @WBT Link works fine for me, very strange.  

If you're running in a private environment where you have info on the networks you want to talk to, you could maintain a file with each of their genesis blocks, then verify via `web3.eth.getBlock(0)` that you're on the chain you need to be on.

If the genesis blocks & chainIds are all identical, meaning that the chains would all be the same chain if it weren't for firewall rules, then maybe you could maintain a "rainbow table" which lets you check which network you're on (i.e. "This txn only exists on NetworkA, so if it's exists rn, I'm on A").

Comment: To be clear, though, unless you can use the networking info (IP, hostname, port) to determine how your node falls into your private firewall rules, I don't think they're going to help you identify which blockchain the machine is running on.  Imagine that you took one of those machines, spun down the current node software, and instead turned on a publicly-visible geth node.  The hostname, IP, and port could remain the same, but you'd be on a different blockchain.  Those networking details are transient and don't identify the chain a node is connected to, you need to use on-chain data for that.